# Finding the gradient vector of a plane along the plane's surface

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

How do you find the gradient vector of a plane?

I have a plane that passes through the origin with the equation

```
        P: 5x + 95y + 46z = 0
```

whose normal vector is therefore, by definition,

```
        n = <5, 95, 46>.
```

I want to know the direction in which the plane is dipping most-steeply - ie. the gradient vector of the plane.

How do I find the gradient vector along the surface of the plane?

Comment: Write the function $z = f(x,y) = (5x + 95y)/(-46)$ and take the gradient $\nabla$ !

Comment: Spot on, @Zubzub

Comment: "dipping most-steeply" with respect to which direction? A plane is, by definition, flat.

Comment: So I get z = f(x,y) = ∇(5x+95y)/(−46) = -5/46 - 95/46 = -100/46.  So does that mean that the gradient vector that will lie along the surface of the plane is V = -5/46x -95/46y - 100/46z?

Comment: @Aretino, I would say with respect to the XY-plane

Answer (score 1):

If $\vec n$ is the normal vector to the plane, you might just consider
$$
\vec v=(\vec n\times\hat z)\times\vec n=(-n_xn_z,-n_yn_z,n_x^2n_y^2).
$$